# Phonegap: How to show configuration screen only once

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have started work on Phonegap and it is very hard for Native App developer to go for Hybrid.

Just want to know that how I can show configuration screen only once in Phonegap. Below is the screenshot. I just want to show it only when user runs an app first time, and not again and again whenever user launches an app and saves IP address.

[image: eConfig Screen]

The problem here is that, whenever I press **back** button of device, this screen gets display.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageConfig"> // This Div needs to show only first time

    <div class="ui-content" data-role="main">
        <h3>Configurations</h3>

        <label for="ipText">IP Address:</label>
        <input type="url" id="ipText" name="ipText" />
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all mc-top-margin-1-5" onclick="saveConfigs()">Save</a>
    </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="pgLgn">

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form id="form1" class="validate">

            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="usrNme">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="usrNme" id="usrNme" placeholder="Username" data-clear-btn="true" data-theme="d" class="required" />
            </div>

            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="pswrd">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="pswrd" id="pswrd" placeholder="Password" data-clear-btn="true" data-theme="d" class="required" />
            </div>

            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chbx-0" class="custom" data-inline="true" />
                <label for="chbx-0">Remember me</label>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Login" id="btnLogin" data-shadow="false" data-theme="a" onclick="OnLoginClick()"/>
            <input type="reset" data-inline="true" value="Reset" data-shadow="false" />

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

What **Cordova Plugin** I need?

**NOTE:** I am using Jquery Mobile and Cordova SQLite Plugin for data storage. And my app is Single Page Architecture.

Thanks in Advance!

Please let me know if not clear.

Comment: Use cookie or sessionStorage in javascript.

Comment: ok! As per sessionStorage, it get erased whenever app is closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670731/sessionstorage-over-localstorage-in-phonegap

Comment: Then see localStorage, it not expire when the app is close

Comment: use localstorage as @TamilSelvan suggested...and also restrict backbutton .

Comment: localStorage does work. Just one more thing! Does it work only in HTML5 or also in previous versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write this line in device ready function.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton",onBackKeyDown,false);

function onBackKeyDown(){

 if($.mobile.activePage.attr("id") == "pgLgn"){
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        else{
            navigator.app.backHistory();
}
}
```

Use [localStorage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_localstorage_localstorage.md.html). Save a simple string with key and check whether there is a particular value against key or not in `deviceready` function.

Comment: change your page id as per your need

Comment: This is good and working. Just tell me, is this only way to handle back button of device?

Comment: I Don't Know...Bt its a convenient way to handle Back Button in Phonegap